# How to publish your research quickly when it pertains to a topical current event?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, research-process

I would like to submit my very current research to some Journal. The work is related to recent hurricane in USA (Hurricane Harvey). Since the peer-review process takes months to publish a work, so I am looking for some well-known journal which can publish my research in maximum 2 weeks with no cost. Would anyone have any idea where and how to publish very current research? or already published their very current research in past?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? What is the point of the two-week deadline?

Comment: What kind of research did you do in the last few days, given that this is something that _just_ happened? Generally, any meaningful research undertaking (worth publishing) takes time to actually _do_. There are probably a few exceptions to this... but very, very few.

Comment: Yes, I understand your points. I have analyzed the tropical extreme events in past 60 years. Though I had finished all works before July, but this hurricane occured when the manuscript was supposed to submit. My boss told to include the recent one also. Thus part of the result highlights the recent hurricane. Anyway, after getting the comments and answers, it is better to get accepted my few months research through peer-review process.

Comment: Scholarly papers aren't like newspaper articles - if something is only of interest because of recent events, maybe a blog would be a better way to disseminate your results than an archival publication?

Comment: What is the intended audience of your research? If you publish too soon after the event, your audience may not see your work as they won't be expecting it. If you're trying to reach a new audience, they may not even care if your work is formally reviewed.

Answer (score 6):

**Quality peer review takes times**: Science takes time and quality peer review takes time. Presumably, you want the stamp of approval that peer review brings. In which case, you will want to publish in a journal where the peer review has meaning. And in this case, peer review takes time. Sure, some fields and journals will get you an initial decision faster than others. But you might get rejected at the first outlet and that can take time; and you might be asked to do revisions somewhere and that takes time to get that outcome, and then for you to make the revisions, and then get an outcome on those revisions. The fastest experience that I've had from submission to in press was about 2 months. And I wouldn't expect to have the same outcome for other work submitted to the same journal.

**Consider sharing a preprint**: One option would be to post your work to a relevant preprint server. I don't know what discipline you are in, but OSF preprints will accept work in any discipline https://osf.io/preprints/

This would allow you to circulate and share your work immediately.
You could then engage in the more time-consuming task of getting your work published in a peer-reviewed journal.

Answer (score 2):

> so I am looking for some well-known journal which can publish my research in maximum 2 weeks with no cost

This is unlikely to exist. There may be well known journals that will publish slowly at no cost, or obscure journals that will publish for free quickly, or predatory journals that will publish quickly for a cost.

But peer review takes time. So a proper publication.

What are you goals? If you want knowledge to be public, you could approach a magazine or newspaper, make a blog post, or post a preprint to ArXiV. This can also help if you want to establish work as yours, so you don't get "scooped".

At the end of the day, the urgent responses to a hurricane will likely come from government scientists, publishing government reports instead of peer-reviewed articles.